# File Handling - exception object is null

Tags: c#

I have this code where I am copying file from one location to another -

```
try
{
    var destination = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileInfo.Name);
    fileInfo.CopyTo(destination); //error thrown at this line
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //log error
}
```

because the destination path was already having file with same name, it threw the exception.
But to my surprise, the exception object was *null*.

I have fixed the issue by using CopyTo overload method to overwrite the existing file -

```
fileInfo.CopyTo(destination, true); //overwrite if file exists
```

which has fixed the issue.

But, my mind still is wondering - why exception object was null?
Any insights please.

Comment: I'm guessing you set a breakpoint _on_ the catch line? The exception variable will be shown as null in the debugger until you step into the catch block.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Thanks for your help. I think, I was half asleep while debugging the issue.